# the process can't access the file because it has been used by another process

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload an image and save it to the database and is giving me an error

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertDepartStaff", connect);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            try
            {

                FileStream filestream = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(filestream);
                image = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)filestream.Length);

                connect.Open();


                //connect.Open();
                SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@StaffID", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
                SqlParameter parm1 = new SqlParameter("@LoginID", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);
                SqlParameter parm4 = new SqlParameter("@StaffRoleID", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm4);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstNameTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lastNameTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userNameTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = passwordTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = phoneTextBox.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffRole", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = staffRoleTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = departmentTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProfilePic", image));

                //clear();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully!");
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }




     public void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";
                ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\maria.ngako\\Desktop\\Icons";
                ofd.FileName.ToString();
                DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {


                    profilePicPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
                    picLoc = ofd.FileName.ToString();
                    profilePicPictureBox.ImageLocation = picLoc;
                }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't see you closing `filestream`...

Comment: Hey maria where's there error ?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to close the file.

**The best way to fix it**

Since you are just reading all the bytes from the file, you can do it like this:

```
image = File.ReadAllBytes(picLoc);
```

**Alternative approaches**

Otherwise, you can change this code:

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(filestream);
image = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)filestream.Length);
```

To this:

```
using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(filestream);
    image = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)filestream.Length);
}
```

This will ensure that the file stream is closed - even if there's an exception when reading the file.

Alternatively, since closing a `BinaryReader` also closes its underlying stream, you can do it like this:

```
using (BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
    image = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)filestream.Length);
}
```

As a sidenote: You were opening the files with `ReadWrite` access. Generally you should open files with the least demanding access; in this case you are only reading them so you should have used `FileAccess.Read`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your `FileStream`, That is why you get an error trying to open it again.

```
filestream.Close();
```

or

```
using(FileStream filestream = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
   //Do operations here
}
```